# People arranged in a queue probability of one standing in front of another

Tags: probability, combinatorics

People $O_1, O_2 \ldots O_{10}$ were arranged in a random queue, find the probability that $0_1$ is directly in front of $O_2$ and $O_5$ is in front of $0_4$, (but not necessarily directly in front of $O_4$).
I know the answer is $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\frac{\binom{9}{2}7!}{10!}$$
but i have no idea where does this answer comes from (Assuming that A and B are those two events described above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lulu's method is simplest, but since you want explanation of the expression, here's another way

$1,$ Remove $O_1$

$2.$ In the 9 objects left, place $O_4...O_5$ in $\dbinom92$ ways and permute the rest in $7!$ ways

$3.$ Replace $O_1$ directly in front of $O_2$

Thus $\dfrac{\dbinom92\cdot7!}{10!}$

Answer (score 1):

The probability of the first event is $\frac 1{10}$: there are $10!$ unconstrained permutations and $9!$ contain the block $O_1O_2$.

Of the permutations containing the block $O_1O_2$ exactly half have $O_5$ in front of $O_4$ (flipping the positions of the two is a symmetry of the situation).

Thus the answer is $\frac 1{20}$.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is trivial so I will not explain.

We first group $O_1$ and $O_2$ as a token and so we have $9$ tokens in total, in which the number $O_4$ before $O_5$ is same as $O_5$ before $O_4$ by symmetry.

So the answer is ${{1\over2}(9!)\over10!}={({9\cdot8\over2})7!\over10!}=\frac{\binom{9}{2}7!}{10!}$

An alternative thinking will be we choose $2$ spots in the $9$ spots for the tokens and put $O_5$ in the earlier spot and $O_2$ in the latter. Then we are left with $7$ spot to permute so $\frac{\binom{9}{2}7!}{10!}$

Comment: I do not understand the series of transformations you posted. I understand the probability for $O_1$ and $O_2$, but do not get how to include the second event.

Comment: If we ignore the second event, then there are $9!$ permutations. Now if we include the second event, we know for each case where $O_5$ is before $O_4$ there is a corresponding case where $O_5$ and $O_4$ are flipped. So the second event halves the permutations we have. This is where ${{1\over2}(9!)\over10!}$ comes from.